# Click delay Browser VS Device, how to improve?

Tags: android, ios, click, ionic2, delay

I'm facing a click delay problem while test my app on real device (IOS/Android) with Ionic2. I have a VirtualList of 5 items according to this template:

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="feed.posts" approxItemHeight="100px"  no-lines>
 <div class="feed-item" *virtualItem="let post">
  <ion-card>
   <ion-row no-padding class="actions-row">
    <ion-col no-padding width-50 text-left>
     <button tappable class="action-button" ion-button clear small icon-left (click)="goToPost(post.id)">
      <ion-icon name='pricetags'></ion-icon>
        {{post.nombrePromotion}} Promotion(s)
     </button>
    </ion-col>
    ...
   </ion-row>
  <ion-card>
 </div>
</ion-list>
```

While testing on browser, clicks are very fast responsive but when I test the app on Iphone 5C or Android devices (or emulator) there is to much delay (like 2s).

Here you can see videos with click delay:

[ON BROWSER](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5uP6YiSgLk)

[ON IPHONE 5C](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oDmY2KiQH8)

**How can i improve clicks speed on device/emulator?**

Thank you

Info:

```
Ionic Framework: 2.2.0
Ionic Native: ^3.5.0
Ionic App Scripts: 1.1.4
Angular Core: 2.4.8
Angular Compiler CLI: 2.4.8
Node: 7.7.3
OS Platform: macOS Sierra
Navigator Platform: MacIntel
```

Answer (score 0):

For mobile/tablet devices use [Gestures](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures).

In this case use `tap`.

```
<button tappable class="action-button" ion-button clear small icon-left (tap)="goToPost(post.id)">
      <ion-icon name='pricetags'></ion-icon>
        {{post.nombrePromotion}} Promotion(s)
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you but (tap) provide exactly the same delay time. This doesn't solve my problem.